# DatePicker in HTML5 setting current date

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I have a problem with my datepicker in HTML5.
I want to set the current date with Javascript but I always get how the date should be provided.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<script>

//Declare variables
var today = new Date();

// Set values
$("#datePicker").val(getFormattedDate(today));

// Get date formatted as YYYY-MM-DD
function getFormattedDate (date) {
    return date.getFullYear()
        + "-"
        + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
        + "-"
        + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
}

</script>
<title>Report</title>
<body>

<h1 align="center">Report f&uuml;r informative Ansichten</h1>

<form action="#" th:action="@{/pdf}" method="post"> 
    <div><input name="datePicker" id="datePicker" type="date" min="1900-01-01" required></div>
    <span class="validity"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="PDF Ausgabe erzeugen"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe someone can tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output of this code?

Comment: I get a box with tt.mm.jjjj inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, however, the script tag is above the the HTML so `$("#datePicker")` is null, because the HTML has not been yet created.

Either place the script below your HTML or wait for `$(document).ready()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Report</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 align="center">Report f&uuml;r informative Ansichten</h1>

<form action="#" th:action="@{/pdf}" method="post"> 
    <div><input name="datePicker" id="datePicker" type="date" min="1900-01-01" required></div>
    <span class="validity"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="PDF Ausgabe erzeugen"/>
</form>


<script>

//Declare variables
var today = new Date();

// Set values
$("#datePicker").val(getFormattedDate(today));

// Get date formatted as YYYY-MM-DD
function getFormattedDate (date) {
    return date.getFullYear()
        + "-"
        + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
        + "-"
        + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you give me some more advice where to put it exactly because I put it underneath the closing form tag and outside the HTML tag but nothing worked.

Comment: @user2806315 Put it directly before the `</body>` closing tag. I updated my answer with the snippet. Also you were missing the `<head>` at the top, take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am dump. Maybe it is too late to work. Thanks!!!!